# Add footnote in abstract on 2 column document

Tags: footnotes, abstract

When using `\footnote` in the abstract part of the document the footnote does not show up at the bottom of the page. Is there any solution to this?

Here is an example:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

    \title{text}
    \author{names}
    \begin{document}
    \twocolumn[
      \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
      \maketitle
      \begin{abstract}
      foo\footnote{faa...}
      \end{abstract}
      \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    \end{document}
```

The number shows up but not the text at the bottom of page.

Comment: Are you using `\maketitle`?

Comment: @Sigur I am using it be before my abstract. When putting it after the abstract gets above the title in the document.

Comment: Which class are you using? Consider using `\thanks{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the `\footnote` into `\footnotemark` inside the `abstract` and `\footnotetext` outside the `\twocolumn[...]` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      {\lipsum*[1]}\footnotemark
    \end{abstract}
    \strut
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\footnotetext{A footnote.}
\section{A section}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another solution is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576440/footenote-disappears-when-i-use-twocolumn-for-abstract-with-affmark-and-aff/576557#576557

Answer (score 0):

With `article` class, the code below works. Is that what you wish?

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{text}
\author{names}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
foo\footnote{faa...}
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is that my document is a 2 column document for everything except the abstract.