# Footenote disappears when I use twocolumn for abstract ? (with \affmark and \affadress not with \thanks)

Tags: header-footer, two-column, abstract, sv-classes

I am writing a paper using \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} for a Springer journal in two column format.  I want to make abstract in one column since it is required in the journal format. Journal also wants the footenotes related to authors and institutions to be seen. I added the codes before and after I made the change.  Using "\twocolumnfalse" trick has made the abstract fit the twocolumns but then the footenotes dissappeared. I check the previous quetions on this issue and observed that some people suggest a solution regarding  "\thanks" BUT in my code I DO NOT use "thanks". Instead, I use "affmark"  and "affadr"
(Since I don't know any other way to write those footenotes in that exact form that the journal asks for). I want my abstract fit in two column and my footenotes not to be dissappeared. Can someone help me with this problem?  Is there any other way of writing my footenote exactly like this? If someone can suggest a different way of writing my footenotes using "\thanks" that may also help.  This footenote is the exact format that the journal asks for.

This is the code after I make the change:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
    %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
    %%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
    %%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
    %%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
    %%EndComments
    gsave
    newpath
    20 20 moveto
    20 220 lineto
    220 220 lineto
    220 20 lineto
    closepath
    2 setlinewidth
    gsave
    .4 setgray fill
    grestore
    stroke
    grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if availab

% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%burada itibaren ekledim%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \title{Title of the Article}
    
    
    
    
    \author{%
        Author 1 Name Surname \protect\affmark[1, 2] \and Author 2 Name Surname\affmark[1] 
    }
    \authorrunning{Esra Yeniaras \and Murat Cenk}
    %\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head
    
    \institute{ 
        \Letter  $ ~~~$Author 1 Name Surname \\
        $~~~~~~~~$author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
        %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
        %\and
        $~~~~~~~$   Author 2 Name Surname \at
        $~~~~~~~$   author1@..edu\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
        %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
    }
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}  
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum
            
            \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.} 
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{intro}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

And below is the code before I made the  abstract change using "\twocolumnfalse".

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
 \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if availab

% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%burada itibaren ekledim%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}



\title{Title of the Article}




\author{%
    Author 1 Name Surname \protect\affmark[1, 2] \and Author 2 Name Surname\affmark[1] 
}
\authorrunning{Author 1 Name Surname \and Author 2 Name Surname}
%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{ 
\Letter  $ ~~~$Author 1 Name Surname \\
$~~~~~~~~$author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
    %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
    %\and
$~~~~~~~$   Author 2 Name Surname \at
$~~~~~~~$   author1@..edu\\ \\
$~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
$~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
    %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum
    
    \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.} 
\end{abstract}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%







\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by lose @twocolumnfalse? and how should I exactly add the \footenote and \footetext?

Comment: You have \begin{@twocolumnfalse} in your code, which is expanded to both a \begingroup and \@twocolumnfalse, while \end{@twocolumnfalse} is expanded as \end@twocolumnfalse (which doesn't exist) and \endgroup.  Any \begingroup ... \endgroup will prevent footnotes from working.  \footnote expands as both \footnotemark and \footntetext, but you need to put the \footnotetext outside the group.  You can lose the [twocolumn] option for svjour3, as  \twocolumn takes care of it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo would it be enough if I use \footenotemark and \footenotetext instead of \affmark and \affadrr? Did you mean this? Or should I add a specific code piece after the \twocolum[]?

Comment: I can't test your code without loading svjour3.cls, which is possible but difficult (assuming I can google the download).

Comment: Here is the link to the download it is under the "Text Formating" section names as: Latex Macro package(Download): https://www.springer.com/journal/13389/submission-guidelines. By the way  I would reaaly appreciate your help since I tried everything and still could not solve the problem? The last thing I tried was using only \twocolumn[abstract here]  without using @twocolumnfalse, and  it worked partially. I mean it worked but it gives the abstract on the next page then. I could not fix that  part.

Comment: Your abstract is too large to fit on one page.  Just use the default abstract, no \twocolumn,  They will just make you change it anyway.  (And thanks for making me load all those packages I will never use again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun.  I seriously doubt the journal will let you do this.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
 \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if availab

% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%burada itibaren ekledim%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym} 

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{everypage}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}



\title{Title of the Article}




\author{%
    Author 1 Name Surname \protect\affmark[1, 2] \and Author 2 Name Surname\affmark[1] 
}
\authorrunning{Author 1 Name Surname \and Author 2 Name Surname}
%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{ 
\Letter  $ ~~~$Author 1 Name Surname \\
$~~~~~~~~$author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
    %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
    %\and
$~~~~~~~$   Author 2 Name Surname \at
$~~~~~~~$   author1@..edu\\ \\
$~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
$~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
    %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\onecolumn
\maketitle
\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{% entire abstract must be formatted in onecolumn
\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum
    
    \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.} 
\end{abstract}}%
\AddThispageHook{\global\csname @twocolumntrue\endcsname}% \afterpage is too late
\afterpage{\twocolumn[\expandafter\unvbox\csname AP@partial\endcsname]}%
\unvbox\tempbox

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%







\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: The footnotes appear just fine for me.  Are your packages up to date?

Comment: Oki sorry my mistake. This works perfectly  fine. Great work. I am not also sure what the journal wants. You are the only person who could answer this problem. I have just realize that some authors leave it as it is and then the editors would modify the code as they wish to fit the the format.  Note sure what to do now:/ Thanks a lot anyway!