# How can I prevent Abstract jumping to the next page in Springer \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} format?

Tags: two-column, abstract, sv-classes

Here is my code below: The "Abstract" word stay in the first page but its text jumps on the next one. Can anyone help me on how to prevent my Abstract text skipping to the next page without making any change in the text appearance?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
    %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
    %%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
    %%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
    %%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
    %%EndComments
    gsave
    newpath
    20 20 moveto
    20 220 lineto
    220 220 lineto
    220 20 lineto
    closepath
    2 setlinewidth
    gsave
    .4 setgray fill
    grestore
    stroke
    grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if availab

% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%burada itibaren ekledim%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    

    
    \title{Title of the Article}
    
    
    
    
    \author{%
        Author 1 Name Surname \protect\affmark[1, 2] \and Author 2 Name Surname\affmark[1] 
    }
    \authorrunning{Esra Yeniaras \and Murat Cenk}
    %\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head
    
    \institute{ 
        \Letter  $ ~~~$Author 1 Name Surname \\
        $~~~~~~~~$author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
        %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
        %\and
        $~~~~~~~$   Author 2 Name Surname \at
        $~~~~~~~$   author1@..edu\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
        %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
    }
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \twocolumn[lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddd
            oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
            oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
            oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
             oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
             oooooooooooooooo
             ooooooooooooooooo
             ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
             oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
             ooooooooooooooooo
             oooooooooooooooooo
             
             ooooooooooooooooooo
            oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      
            \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3 bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3  \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3} ]
        \end{abstract}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{intro}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some dummy text in the abstract, comment the `\twocolumn` and everything will be fine.

```
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
%\twocolumn[
\lipsum[1] 
\keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3 bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3  \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3}
%]
\end{abstract}
```

[image: x1]

I also change your `\institute` definition to

```
    \institute{ 
    Author 1 Name Surname \\
    author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
    %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
    %\and
    Author 2 Name Surname \at
    author1@..edu\\ \\
    \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
    \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
    %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
    }
```

just to be able to compile without errors, and commented `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to make the section titles appear with bold face.

**UPDATE** To have the abstract span two columns

[image: X3]

you have to use a one-column class, for example `\documentclass{svjour3}`  and then use the package `multicols` you already loaded for the rest of the paper. (Several packages are loaded twice, including this one).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1] 
\keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3 bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3  \and bla3.bla3.bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3}
%]
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}    
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the journal wants the abstact  fit two columns. So I am not allowed to delete \twocloumn . Without it, there is no jumping problem. My  main point is to keep \twocolumn  commmand and don't let abstract text float to the next page at the same time. I tried using \@twocolumnfalse group but than the footnotes dissapper.(And tried every possible solution to keep the right format but could not manage to do it). That's why I need something different for this question. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Please see the updated answer,

Comment: Thanks but  I just check the submission guidelines and it says: "
Manuscripts should be submitted in LaTeX. Please use Springer’s LaTeX macro package and choose the formatting option “twocolumn”." So unfortunately we are not allowed to switch to the onecolumn format:( Thanks for your efforts though. Information you provide is really useful anyway. I wish they were more flexible though.

Comment: Oki  the answer is here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576440/footenote-disappears-when-i-use-twocolumn-for-abstract-with-affmark-and-aff/576557#576557

Comment: When I apply the updated 2 answer, the footnotes disappears.  That was the reason I used just \twocolumn instead of \@twocolumnfalse trick. The problem is answered by the link I provided above with no bugs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please rewrite your question. What you were looking was not related with the Abstract jumping to the next page. Glad you found the answer yourself.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks a lot. I wanted to accept your answer a lot but I thought it would misguide others since there is a more strict answer on the other side. I mean the other solution does not change the appeance of the text and that was the point. Thanks a lot anyway. I really appreciate your efforts.