# how to make a one column abstract in two column without changing institute place?

Tags: two-column, abstract, author

I have a two column article in which I want to make a one column abstract, when I use:

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\journalname....
\begin{document}
\title ....
\author...
\institute...
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      ...
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
  ]
```

The abstract becomes a in one column but the institute information disappears which should appear in the bottom left of the first page, can anybody please help ?

(the image is how the first page shows before i change abstract into one column, with authors showing in bottom left)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to our community! Please provide a minimal working example for your question. This will help other users test your code and provide you with an appropriate answer. Check out the minimal working example guidelines: https://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

You might start with `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`,    switch to one column for the title and abstract, and then, using the package `multicol` switch to the original two column mode.

All the floats will go to the next page.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{graphicx}% added <<<
\usepackage{multicol} % added <<<

\journalname{to be decided journal}

\begin{document}
            
\title{Insert the  title of the article  here}

\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle? If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}


\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: \today / Accepted: a much later date}

%%****************
\onecolumn
\maketitle
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{%  abstract and title in onecolumn
    \begin{abstract}
         As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason
        is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown
        elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
        
        \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.} 
\end{abstract}}%    
%%****************  

\begin{multicols}{2}  % start two columns again <<<<<<<<<
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Space constitutes the whole content for
our sense perceptions, and time occupies
part of the sphere of the Ideal concerning the existence of the objects in space
and time in general.

\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
2. Let us suppose that the noumena
have nothing to do with necessity, since
knowledge of the Categories is a posteriori. Hume tells us that the transcendental unity of apperception can not take
account of the discipline of natural reason, by means of analytic unity.

\begin{figure*}
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{One-column wide figure}
    \label{fig:1}      
\end{figure*}

3. As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things in themselves (and
it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a representation of time. Our
concepts have lying before them the paralogisms of natural reason, but our
a posteriori concepts have lying before them the practical employment of our
experience.

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Two-column wide figure}
\label{fig:2}      
\end{figure*}

\begin{table*}
    \caption{Table caption is above the table}
    \label{tab:1}     
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
        first & second & third  \\
        \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
        number & number & number \\
        number & number & number \\
        \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{Conclusions}

Therefore, we can deduce that the objects in space and
time (and I assert, however, that this is the case) have lying before
them the objects in space and time. Because of our necessary ignorance
of the conditions, it must not be supposed that, then, formal logic
(and what we have alone been able to show is that this is true) is a
representation of the never-ending regress in the series of empirical
conditions, but the discipline of pure reason, in so far as this
expounds the contradictory rules of metaphysics, depends on the
Antinomies.


\begin{acknowledgements}
If you'd like to thank anyone, place your comments here
and remove the percent signs.
\end{acknowledgements}

\end{multicols} % end two colunmns <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your answer, your suggestion worked although i'm not sure i can change the documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}, since it was one of the instructions made by springer in the guidelines

Comment: @Nissrine If you must strictly follow the instructions, the abstract should be in one column.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576440/footenote-disappears-when-i-use-twocolumn-for-abstract-with-affmark-and-aff/602846#602846 because it's exactly my case, but when i try it the introduction becomes in one column too

Comment: @Nissrine See the updated answer using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`

Comment: it partially solved it but now the footnote are in one column, i used the package {dblfnote} to get it back to two column, it did do it but that's not really how it should look, the authors information supposed to be in the left corner and without making the introduction text move to next page when it reaches the footnotes section (i don't know if i explained well, i can't add a picture in the comment) .. it's like the authors should be in two column format but actually showing only in the left column of the two without interrupting the continuity of the text.

Comment: Is it possible to let first left column to be full and followed by the second column. On this solution both columns are equally filled

Comment: @alper For the benefit of other readers, I suggest you ask a new question on this topic.